# I cannot connect two sheets using vlookup

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to connect the `program_name` column to `program_name_id` from `p_programs` sheet.

Here are the sheets:

`p_session_list`
[image]

`p_programs`
[image]

I have the following code:

```
=vlookup(B2, p_programs!A2:C79, 3)
```

But it says that my syntax is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use the fourth criterion of `False`
2. Your formulas will require `;` in place of `,` :

```
=vlookup(B2; p_programs!A2:C79; 3; FALSE)
```

Comment: Hey Scott, aparently the formula actualy works, but there is still something wrong. http://prntscr.com/irubhg Have a look please?

Comment: I don't know what that means in english.

Comment: AD means, NAME, does it help?

Comment: Then you need to translate VLOOKUP into your language.

Comment: Thanks, I will keep trying!

Comment: what is you language?

Comment: try `=DÜŞEYARA(...`

Comment: Still the same result, I think I will try joining tables from sql should be so much easier :)

Answer (score 1):

Try running this short sub procedure.

```
sub makeLocalFormula()
    with worksheets("p_session_list")
        .range("s2:s10").formula = "=vlookup(B2, p_programs!A2:C79, 3, false)"
    end with
end sub
```

After running it, go back to the p_session_list worksheet and see what formula is in column S.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it seems like me and excel are not good together. ;/ I will try querying the SQL.